# Retrieve and butcher horse skeleton from refuse pile?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I had a horse die of starvation while I was still learning about the game.  I couldn't figure out how to to butcher it, but did manage to get it to an outdoor refuse pile before it stunk up the place.  Now there is a skeleton there, and I can't figure out how to retrieve it so that I can turn it into bone.

How do I turn a skeleton that is in an outdoor refuse pile into usable bone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of Dwarf Fortress' many quirks is that creatures who died of starvation are completely un-butcherable. [It's a known bug.](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=1275)

Apparently, the only way Dwarves are satisfied eating 'Tame' animals, is if they've killed the animal with their own two hands via a butcher's shop (read: [murder](/questions/tagged/murder)) either by manually toggling the animal for slaughter with <kbd>v</kbd> or via the animals subsection of the stocks screen (<kbd>z</kbd>).

Comment: Perhaps they are superstitious about eating an animal that died in such a inhumane way :/

Comment: @AraonLS - they won't eat animals that die of old age, either. Not sure you can get any more humane (dwarfane?) than that.